# PHP Group Json Objects

Tags: php, json

```
 "forms": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "new_patient",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "created_at": "2017-10-24 05:12:24",
                "updated_at": "2017-10-24 05:12:24",
                "pivot": {
                    "institution_id": 1,
                    "form_id": 1,
                    "field_name_id": 21,
                    "field_caption": "Gön.Hekim"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "new_patient",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "created_at": "2017-10-24 05:12:24",
                "updated_at": "2017-10-24 05:12:24",
                "pivot": {
                    "institution_id": 1,
                    "form_id": 1,
                    "field_name_id": 22,
                    "field_caption": "Kurum"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "new_patient",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "created_at": "2017-10-24 05:12:24",
                "updated_at": "2017-10-24 05:12:24",
                "pivot": {
                    "institution_id": 1,
                    "form_id": 1,
                    "field_name_id": 23,
                    "field_caption": "Endikasyon"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "edit_patient",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "created_at": "2017-10-24 05:12:24",
                "updated_at": "2017-10-24 05:12:24",
                "pivot": {
                    "institution_id": 1,
                    "form_id": 2,
                    "field_name_id": 24,
                    "field_caption": "Materyal"
                }
            }
        ]
```

I want to group forms object in same name/id.

How i want...

```
"forms": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "new_patient",
                    "deleted_at": null,
                    "created_at": "2017-10-24 05:12:24",
                    "updated_at": "2017-10-24 05:12:24",
                    "fields": [{
                        "field_name_id": 21,
                        "field_caption": "Gön.Hekim"
                    },{
                        "field_name_id": 22,
                        "field_caption": "Kurum"
                    },{
                        "field_name_id": 23,
                        "field_caption": "Endikasyon"
                    }]
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "edit_patient",
                    "deleted_at": null,
                    "created_at": "2017-10-24 05:12:24",
                    "updated_at": "2017-10-24 05:12:24",
                    "fields": [{
                        "field_name_id": 24,
                        "field_caption": "Materyal"
                    }]
                }
            ]
```

i searched in so and googled, but i could not find any method for my problem. There are answers to similar questions.

i did with foreach loop but i thought may be there is a method for this in php.

And also, if i have over an hundred objects in json, foreach can be slow.

Thanks in advice.

Comment: Did the provided solution work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$arr = json_decode($str, true);
$arr2 = [];
$ids = [];
foreach($arr['forms'] as $form)
{
    if(!in_array($form['id'], $ids))
    {
        $ids[] = $form['id'];
        $arr2[$form['id']] = $form;
    }
    unset($arr2[$form['id']]['pivot']);
    $arr2[$form['id']]['fields'][] = [$form['pivot']['field_name_id'], $form['pivot']['field_caption']];
}
$str2 = json_encode(['forms' => array_values($arr2)]);

echo $str2;
```

This uses a `foreach` loop to get unique forms and will create a new key `fields` to hold the `field_name_id` and `field_caption` and also removes the `pivot` key